# How to Convert XML file with attributes to an array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I try to convert a simple xml file to an array but the conversion do not keep the "id" attributes as the key array.
XML source:

```
<mapi>
    <categoriesList>
        <category id="310">Autres</category>
        <category id="574">Bière</category>
        <category id="495">Biscuits</category>
        <category id="444">Bonbons</category>
        <category id="435">Champagne</category>
        <category id="371">Cidre</category>
        <category id="215">Condiments</category>
        <category id="8">Fruits</category>
        <category id="445">Poissons</category>
        <category id="578">Produits laitiers</category>
        <category id="539">Spiritueux</category>
        <category id="259">Viandes</category>
        <category id="126">Vin</category>
    </categoriesList>
</mapi>
```

Id like a simple array like this:

```
array (
    [310] => Autres
    [574] => Bière
    [495] => Biscuits
    [444] => Bonbons 
    [435] => Champagne
    [371] => Cidre
    [215] => Condiments
    [8] => Fruits 
    [445] => Poissons
    [578] => Produits laitiers
    [539] => Spiritueux
    [259] => Viandes
    [126] => Vin
)
```

Thank your for your help
Dimitri

Comment: Where's your code? What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function XMLtoArray($xml) {
    $xmlArray = array();
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->load($xml);
    $categories = $dom->getElementsByTagName("category");
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $id = $category->getAttribute("id");
        $xmlArray[$id] = $category->nodeValue;
    }
    return($xmlArray);
}
```

Then call the function like so:

```
$myArray = XMLtoArray("path/to/file.xml");
```

Comment: Not a problem; feel free to choose this as the answer if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include ("htmlparser.php");
    $string = '
<mapi>
    <categoriesList>
        <category id="310">Autres</category>
        <category id="574">Bière</category>
        <category id="495">Biscuits</category>
        <category id="444">Bonbons</category>
        <category id="435">Champagne</category>
        <category id="371">Cidre</category>
        <category id="215">Condiments</category>
        <category id="8">Fruits</category>
        <category id="445">Poissons</category>
        <category id="578">Produits laitiers</category>
        <category id="539">Spiritueux</category>
        <category id="259">Viandes</category>
        <category id="126">Vin</category>
    </categoriesList>
</mapi>
';
 $html = str_get_html($string);
  foreach($html->find('category') as $element){
    $array[] = $element -> innertext ;
  }

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($array);
?>
```

You need to download this library: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_dump

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple task with [`SimpleXMLElement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php):

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$asarray = array();
foreach ($sxe->categoriesList->category as $c) {
    $asarray[(int) $c['id']] = (string) $c;
}

var_export($asarray);
```